# Meteor framework free server crashes

Tags: javascript, meteor

Hi I just learned Meteor and developed a multiplayer game. For testing purposes, I deployed to the free server and each night we play the game with some friends, generally 20 online people. However, from time to time, website crashes and no data is coming in or out. It just freezes. I checked the client logs and server logs but nothing is there. When I refresh the page, it freezes on the loading template.

I use iron router for the loading screen:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'main',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

Router.route('/loading', {
  template : 'loading'
});

Router.route('/', {
  template : 'home',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [Meteor.subscribe('chat'),Meteor.subscribe('games'),Meteor.subscribe('users')];
  },  
  data : function(){
    return {
      chat : Chat.find({},{sort: {createdAt: 1}}),
      games : Games.find({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}}),
      users : Meteor.users.find({},{sort : {"status.online":-1}})
    }
  }
});
```

I have no idea about the problem. Sometimes it freezes on the main page, sometimes on the game page. For the game page, I am simplifying my code for you to understand.

There are 2 levels in the game: days and nights. It starts with the click of the game-creator and morning starts with a countdown. When countdown ends, night starts with a corresponding countdown. And it continues to loop until the game finishes. At the end of morning, there are some computations for the game and then it switches to night. Night is also the same.

For countdown purpose I use setTimeOut() function with a Fiber.

```
Meteor.methods({
    startGame : function(id){
        //some other code here
        //....

        //set timestamp of the end date
        var currentDate = new Date();
        console.log("currentDate: "+currentDate);
        if(night){ var interval = durationNight;}
        else{ var interval = durationMorning;}
        console.log("interval: "+interval);
        var endDate = currentDate.setSeconds(currentDate.getSeconds() + interval);
        console.log("endDate: "+endDate);

        Games.update({"_id" : id}, {$set : {"endTime" : endDate}});


        endLevelInternal[id] = setTimeout(function () {
            // // completed
            Fiber(function() { 
                console.log(id +' countdown completed');

                endLevelFlag[id] = true;

                if(endLevelFlag[id]){
                    endLevelFlag[id] = false;
                    Meteor.call('endLevel', id, function(){
                        endLevelFlag[id] = true;
                    });
                }
            }).run();  

        }, interval*1000);
    },

    endLevel : function(){
        //some other code here
        //...

        //
        if(!finished){
            Meteor.call('startGame', id);   
        }
    }
});

Template.game.events({
    'click .startGame' : function(evt, template){
        var flag = true;
        if(flag){
            flag = false;
            Meteor.call('startGame', template.data._id, function(){
                flag = true;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I am not sure if the problem is because of the server code or because of the limitations of the free server (RAM or CPU).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest having a look at the Meteor logs, or deploying on some other platform that is production ready.
One option is AWS or DigitalOcean using Meteor Up.

Comment: I tried to check both client and  server logs, nothing is there. Also checked the network debugging from Chrome console when it freezes, "websocket" HTTP header is 101. However, it is 101 when it is working as well. I will try to deploy to Modulus today and check there.

Comment: Add kadira and see what the ram and cpu look like. I'm not really sure how this works on Meteor hosting

Comment: But either way meteor.com hosting isn't meant for production. The all randomly crashing is probably not  a bug in your code

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who has the same problem. I just deployed my application from free server to Modulus and everything works fine now. So it must be something with the Meteor free server.